# NdefRecord crash is device dependent

Tags: android, nfc

I have the weird situation that one line of code makes one phone crash, another one not. The specific line ist the one where I create the new NdefRecord(). I have included the code snippet below. While the version in comments works on both phones, I still wonder why I see this effect.

The reference on the constructor for NdefRecord (short tnf, byte[] type, byte[] id, byte[] payload) is unclear to me. According to the source code it should never work with null as parameters ([source at Grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/nfc/NdefRecord.java#NdefRecord.%3Cinit%3E%28short,byte%5B%5D,byte%5B%5D,byte%5B%5D%29)).

```
 private void setNdefBinary(byte[] bdata, int size, int index) {
    NdefRecord record;
    byte[] payload;

    // copy bytes into payload
    payload = new byte[size + 1];
    payload[0] = (byte) (index & 0xff);
    System.arraycopy(bdata, 0, payload, 1, size);

    /* this works on Xperia S and Samsung S3
        byte[] empty = new byte[0]; 
        record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, empty, payload); */

        // this crashes on Xperia S, but works on Samsung S3
        record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, null, null, payload);

    ndefRecords[index] = record;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing different implementations of NdefRecord in the Android SDK. The later Android SDKs allow for empty arguments, the earlier do not.

Android >= 16 accepts null payloads. Pass inn empty byte arrays to make it all backwards-compatible.